# rpmbuild - How to mark some package as conflicting at build time

Tags: gcc, mocking, rpm, rpmbuild

I have to use different compiler (gcc) from one packaged with centos. It is also gcc, just repacked newer version which has been installed with different path.

I am using mock for build, which has in its basic setup

**config_opts['chroot_setup_cmd'] = 'groupinstall build'**

Group build in my case contains CentOS stock gcc. I cannot change anything in mock environment.

Is there a way how to delete gcc package before build actually proceed?

The problem is that some programs compiled by my repacked gcc tends to use system /usr/include/ instead of correct include's from repacked gcc, so I am looking for a way how to localize problem.

Comment: I haven't used mock before so I can't give a real answer here.. but is there any reason why adding `rm -f $(rpm -ql gcc)` to the `%prep` section won't work here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [instructions provided by Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_Mock_to_test_package_builds?rd=Extras/MockTricks#Building_packages_that_depend_on_packages_not_in_a_repository) to complete this task, they talk about doing a build when the rpm you need to install isn't part of a repo.

If that doesn't work I would look at setting up a custom environment, or asking your admin to do so if you cannot change it as you state in your question. The configuration files are stored under /etc/mock/*.cfg. I would suggest copying one of these that matches your needs and naming it something unique. Then you need to add an additional repo line (either local or remote depending on where your custom copy of GCC lives).

This will configure the environment to pick up that version of GCC if it really is just marked as a newer release. In the event there is some unique naming convention or it's not being picked up for some reason you should look at modifying the chroot_setup_cmd to simply install all the build packages. When I review a

```
yum groupinstall buildsys-build
```

I see a list of all the associated packages. You'll obviously want to check 'build'. You can then modify your config_opts['chroot_setup_cmd'] to use 'install', instead of 'groupinstall', where you can then install all the associated build packages, as well as your custom GCC.

If that still doesn't work, you can always copy the build packages to your own personal repo where GCC lives, ensure that's the only one available to pull from, configure the repo so it supports the 'build' group, and then build the package. While not extremely helpful due to age, the [Mock docs](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/MockSetupUsingLocalMirror) have some useful information for configuring your environment with local repos.